# How to execute a Powershell (.ps1) file in Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

```
Run, powershell.exe C:\Users\user1\PoweShell\Duplicate Selected Files.ps1
```

Running the above example just opens the blue powershell CMD window and it quickly flashes, the script does not run.

Running the below example opens the blue powershell CMD window and keeps it open, the script does not run.

```
Run, powershell.exe /k C:\Users\user1\AppLib\Executables\PoweShell\Duplicate Selected Files.ps1
```

I should mention in file explorer, double clicking a `.ps1` file opens it in notepad, I should like to keep this behaviour. I can achieve the same  in Autohotkey with:

```
Run, C:\Users\user1\AppLib\Executables\PoweShell\Duplicate Selected Files.ps1
```

I can execute `.ps1` script files in file explorer by rich clicking and choosing `Run with Powershell`. How can I achieve this same result in Autohotkey?

PS: I know I can run Poweshell directly in Autohotkey with `RunWait, powershell.exe -NoExit -Command "Something here..."` I really need to how to execute `.ps1` files saved to folders.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I have taken the liberty to crosspost this question on other forums as well.

Comment: I commend to your attention [Microsoft Docs on the PowerShell command-line parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1). `/k` is used by `CMD`, not by PowerShell.

Comment: Maybe this can help you.

https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=50550

Comment: @JeffZeitlin That link is exactly what I was in desperate search for a few days!! I did trawl the powershell docs page and I could not find a central page of commands that these external programs were using to invoke powershell outside of powershell!! argh  I even found a NoExit parameter. I kid you not I was using a screen recorder to read output errors because the terminal kept closing too fast for me, I mean I know programmers have high standard for reading speed but that was just too fast! I am so happy for that. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

**First Way**
Create a variable to store the path to ps1 script.

```
strPsScriptFile := "F:\psScript\test.ps1"
```

Run the powershell script as below, use Runwait to keep the shell open

```
Run, PowerShell.exe  -NoExi  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command %strPsScriptFile%
```

Incase you want to pass parameters to ps1 script. Ex: pass a Name as first and age as second

```
 Run, PowerShell.exe  -NoExi  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command %strPsScriptFile% " Chanu 10"
```

**Second Way**

```
; hide the terminal
    DetectHiddenWindows, On
;path to ps1
    Path_To_File := "test.ps1"
    Target := "PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File " PathToFile
; terminal location
    vComSpec := A_ComSpec ? A_ComSpec : ComSpec
;run the terminal
    Run, % vComSpec,, Hide, vPID
    WinWait, % "ahk_pid " vPID
    DllCall("kernel32\AttachConsole", "UInt",vPID)
    oShell := ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell")
    oExec := oShell.Exec(Target)
    vStdOut := ""
    while !oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream{
            ; you can read the the output till the execution ends 
    }
    DllCall("kernel32\FreeConsole")
    Process, Close, % vPID
```

**Reference :**

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/
https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/ey3pmb/get_hidden_cmdpowershell_output/